# load async configs before export

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I need to load some async config before run my app, something like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var myModule = require("myModule");

myModule.create().generateModel().then(tagger => {

    router.post('/tag', function(req, res, next) {
        res.json(tagger.tag(req.body.text));
    });

   module.exports = router;
});
```

but this does not work because require is sync. How can I make this work? How can I reutilize "tagger" in other modules?

Comment: I'm not sure you can set module.exports dynamically like that. When Node bootstraps the app, it creates closures for each module. The entry points are defined by what's exported to the module (module.exports). Would love to know if I'm wrong for the learnings...

Comment: What about exporting a function that returns a promise?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set `module.exports` asynchronously because you're exporting the `router` which is already defined synchronously:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var myModule = require("myModule");

myModule.create().generateModel().then(tagger => {
    router.post('/tag', function(req, res, next) {
        res.json(tagger.tag(req.body.text));
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Thank you. But in this case server will be running before routes be created.

Comment: @MuriloKunze why does that matter?

Comment: I really dont know hahaha. I just think it is the right sequence.